# slick.js carousel dosen't work at height percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use slick.js carousel and I simplify css a little bit to fix that error but I think the problem is from javascript.

If I add to `.slick-slide` height in pixels, works. But if I want to use percentage, slider get auto-height. Form where, I really don't know. I try to put `height: 100% !important;` add classes with height, remove, but nothing work.

Here is [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVzRzN) exemple

Answer (score 1):

For height to work in percentages, you need to set height for all parent divs. Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVjadW

```
html, body, #myCarousel, #myCarousel div{
  height:100%;
}

#myCarousel .slick-slide {
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You are awsome. Thanks. Works. Off-topic: I don't have enought reputation to vote up. Sorry. I will come back.

Comment: One question: You use that : #myCarousel, #myCarousel div. What do that "div" after MyCarousel?

Comment: " #myCarousel,, #myCarousel div" is to ensure that the "#myCarousel" div and all divs inside that has their heights set to 100%

Comment: "myCarousel" for give 100% height that id. And "myCarousel div" give .image, .caption and everything inside that ID height 100%. Hmh. I understood. Thanks :d